# React textarea component will be very slow after 1million characters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, textarea

In React text area component becomes very slow after 1 million characters. Actually, I am passing child data to parent data. I don't know how can I solve this problem.

Comment: Would be nice with some code... But, guessing that you probably update the state `onChange` is probably your problem. Should change to focusLost or other event that do not update on every keystroke.

Comment: Even simple textarea is causing a problem. As a testing I only added the simple  <textarea></textarea> but still it is lagging to adding new characters after >1m characters

Comment: Would still be easier if we see the full code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-debounce-input for your input.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-debounce-input